# Angular2 share data between component different modules

Tags: angular2-services

I have requirement where i need to share data between modules , 
my folder structure is something like this

```
app(folder)
  app.module.ts
  app.component.ts
service(folder)
  abc.service.ts
student(folder)
  student.module.ts
  student.component.ts
```

here i have abc.service.ts file in which i am setting some data like

```
    private scoreList= new Subject<any>();
   setList(val){
      this.scoreList.next(val);
    }

    getList(){
      return this.scoreList.asObservable();
    }
```

In app.module.ts

```
     declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    studentModule,
    HttpModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    abcService
  ],
```

in app.component.ts i am calling api and setting it to setList, and trying to fetch value in student.component.ts but i am not getting value, when i put debugger inside getList its showing array of 0 length when i was inside setList function it was showing value.

Thanks

Comment: The way I've handled this is to put the service in a module, SharedModule, and then import this module into any modules that need the service.

Answer (score 0):

Here iam created working example for you, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gebnnq

app.component.ts

```
// iam declared sample data you can replace whatever data array.
records = [
      { CategoryID: 1, CategoryName: "Beverages", Description: "Coffees, teas" },
      { CategoryID: 2, CategoryName: "Condiments", Description: "Sweet and savory sauces" },
      { CategoryID: 3, CategoryName: "Confections", Description: "Desserts and candies" }    
    ];

  constructor(private _abc:AbcService){

    this._abc.setList(this.records);
    console.log("Service Value has been set",this._abc.scoreList);
  }
```

app.html

```
<app-student></app-student>
```

app.module.ts

```
import { AbcService } from './abc.service';
import { StudentComponent } from './student/student.component'

declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent,StudentComponent ]
```

app.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class AbcService {
    private scoreList: any[] = [];

    constructor() { }

    setList(val) {
        this.scoreList = val;
    }

    getList() {
        return this.scoreList;
    }
}
```

Student.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AbcService } from '../abc.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-student',
  templateUrl: './student.component.html'
})
export class StudentComponent implements OnInit {
  result:any[]=[];
  constructor(private _abc:AbcService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.result=this._abc.getList();
    //also use like, this.result=this._abc.scoreList
    console.log("Result Value get from Student Component",this.result);
  }

}
```

Student.html

```
Here Displayed Results
<ng-container *ngIf="result">
  <li *ngFor="let item of result">
  {{item.CategoryName}}
  </li>
</ng-container>
```

Here iam solved your requirement based on sample data replace your data.

screenshot,

[image]

I hope it's helpful.

Thanks,

Muthukumar